# Existing values of some columns are not displayed in QuickEdit view?

Tags: column, view, bug, quick-edit

If I use QuickEdit in a document library, some of the custom columns seem to be empty. In fact, they already contain values.

- Is this a known bug?
- Does anybody have an idea, what could be the problem?

THis is a very serious and annoying problem as it makes it quite impossible to change the metadata for a large number of documents at once!

### Example

1) QuickEdit view: Column "DocumentLanguage" is empty!
[image]
2) Normal view: but the values are there!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it turned out, that the following caused the problem:

the structure of the site collection its contained libraries was created semi-automatically by Windows PowerShell scripts and some settings were not set correctly and lead to that problem